# SharePoint 2013 document set multilevel approval workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-set, approval

How to create a **multilevel approval workflow for document set** in designer? . While uploading the documents user will select "Do you want to start the workflow ?" If it's Yes the document set approval workflow should send email for approval . System should be able to reassign the task too. It's a SharePoint 2013 environment .

The problem is when user will select "Do you want to start the workflow now ?"=Yes , then I need to send a single email to get approval for all the documents in the document set .

I tried "**Start Document set approval process** " action in SP2010 Workflow but it's not creating task . & If I will use "start approval process" action then its not updating document metadata's.

Kindly share your comments. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If coding is feasible for your team. You can build a event receiver to trigger the workflow whenever someone upload a document.

By using only SharePoint Designer, you may build a workflow that will be triggered whenever a document is uploaded. Your library should contain a Yes/No column named "Do you want to start the workflow?". Hence, when a user uploaded a document, the workflow will be triggered and check whether it should continue the approval process.

Also, you can use SharePoint designer to customize the workflow steps. By adding multiple "Start Approval Process" actions you can have a multi-level approval workflow. For instance, you can add 3 columns "approver1" "approver2" "approver3" in your library, then have your workflow ask for these 3 approvers' action.

Comment: Hi Mark , Thanks for your suggestions. Coding is not possible . The problem is when user will select  "Do you want to start the workflow now ?"=Yes , then I need to send a single  email to get approval for all the documents  in the document set . I tried "Start Document set approval process " action in SP2010 Workflow but it's not creating task . & If I will use "start approval process" action then its not updating document metadata's . Thanks!

Comment: The "Start Approval Process", iirc, should contain an action to create a task item in Task list. Since you can freely add/modify actions in your workflow. You only need to spend time to dig what is missed in the flow.